# How to go to previous date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have to check expiry date of vehicle, I have taken interval of 1 day but its taking positive value so its not showing as EXPIRED rather its taking the positive value and showing as EXPIRES TOMORROW.

```
SELECT   
vehicle_reg_num,
vehicle_type,
insurance_validity,
tax_validity,
fc_validity
 FROM vms_vehicles_list 
WHERE ((insurance_validity BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
OR insurance_validity BETWEEN DATE_ADD (NOW(),INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW()) 
OR (tax_validity BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
OR tax_validity BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW())
OR (fc_validity BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) 
OR fc_validity BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW()) 
AND vehicle_delete_flag=0;
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this.

```
    SELECT 
vehicle_reg_num,
vehicle_type,
insurance_validity,
tax_validity,
fc_validity
 FROM vms_vehicles_list 
WHERE ((insurance_validity BETWEEN NOW() AND SUBDATE(NOW(),7) 
OR insurance_validity BETWEEN SUBDATE(NOW(),7) AND NOW()) 
OR (tax_validity BETWEEN NOW() AND SUBDATE(NOW(),7) 
OR tax_validity BETWEEN SUBDATE(NOW(),7) AND NOW()) 
OR (fc_validity BETWEEN NOW() AND SUBDATE(NOW(),7))) 
OR fc_validity BETWEEN SUBDATE(NOW(),7) AND NOW()) AND vehicle_delete_flag=0;
```

Comment: Please provide an answer instead of question format suggestions.

Comment: @mukesh, please check it is answer not for suggestion for question formate.. please read properly.

Comment: @Mukesh, why you edit answer and question format regardless?